# issue converting to UTC from PST using dateutil

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, epoch, python-dateutil

My local machine current time zone is:

```
Mon May 20 17:44:50 PDT 2019
```

So when I do a epoc conversion of `2019-04-01T00:00:00` I get : `1554102000`

I should be getting `1554076800`  according to www.epochconverter.com

my function looks like this:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import *
from dateutil.tz import *

input =  '2019-04-01T00:00:00'

def convert_to_UTC_epoc(input):
    utc_zone = tz.gettz('UTC')
    pattern = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'
    local_time = local_time.replace(tzinfo=local_zone)
    utc_time = datetime.strptime(date_time,pattern).astimezone(utc_zone)
    epoch = int(utc_time.timestamp())
    return epoch
```

I thought that using `utc_zone = tz.gettz('UTC')` puts it into the correct timezone but for some reason I'm still 7hrs off.

Comment: There does not seem to be enough information to see what's going on here. `local_time` is used before definition, and `local_zone` is never defined.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure because the code in your question seems to be missing definitions for `local_time` and `local_zone`, but I suspect that the problem you are having stems from the fact that `timestamp()` gives you a unix time, which has no notion of time zone - it is an absolute timestamp expressed in number of seconds* since the unix epoch, observe:

```
dt = datetime(2019, 1, 1, tzinfo=tz.gettz("America/Los_Angeles"))
print(dt)
# 2019-01-01 00:00:00-08:00

dt2 = dt.astimezone(tz.UTC)
print(dt2)
# 2019-01-01 08:00:00+00:00
```

`dt` and `dt2` both represent the same absolute time here, but in different time zones, as you can see reflected in the different local times. Because they represent the same instant in time, if I convert these to `timestamp`, I get the same value:

```
print(dt.timestamp())
# 1546329600.0

print(dt2.timestamp())
# 1546329600.0
```

The UTC offset information is lost in this process. If you want to retain it, I recommend storing it separately.

**Edit**: Sorry, again, I now realize there's another problem you could be having, depending on what your code snippet was intended to do in the first place.

Because `.timestamp()` always converts to UTC automatically, your `astimezone` call does nothing. If you want a function that takes as input a string, parses it with the pattern `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'`, interpreting that as a time in `America/Los_Angeles` (Pacific time), and returning the epoch representation of that, you want this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import tz

pattern = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'
PACIFIC = tz.gettz("America/Los_Angeles")

def dtstr_pst_to_epoch(date_string):
    # Get datetime with no time zone information attached
    naive_time = datetime.strptime(date_string, pattern)

    # Reinterpret the naive datetime as being in Pacific time
    pacific_time = naive_time.replace(tzinfo=PACIFIC)

    # Return epoch representation
    return pacific_time.timestamp()
```

Naive times are interpreted as machine-local times, which means that `naive_time.astimezone(tz.UTC)` or `naive_time.timestamp()` would give a result that depends on the time zone settings for the computer you're running it on.